# Android Toolbar menu item background

Tags: android, xml, android-styles, android-menu

How can I achieve the styling effect as in the Youtube app for the **Username** icon in the top right of the screenshot of the YouTube app below?

[image: YouTube App Screenshot]

Currently, I have the following styles for the application

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/color_accent</item>
    <item name="otpViewStyle">@style/OtpWidget.OtpView</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance" >@style/home_menu_style</item>
</style>

<style name="home_menu_style" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

The other issue is that the text colour is black, instead of white. I have defined the text colour as white in the styles as well as in the toolbar definition

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:titleTextColor="@color/white">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

[image: My Application Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question is in the following link:

[Styling toolbar menu item title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887764/styling-toolbar-menu-item-title)

It is the same question, with more context

Answer (score 0):

make a drawable file like below

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid
    android:color="#48b3ff"/>
```

and use like this.

```
<style name="home_menu_style" parent="AppTheme">
<item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
<item name="android:backGround">@drawable/your_custom_drawable</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
```