# space between icon and title item in menu when call it in toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have the following menu:

```
   <menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_main_help"
                    android:title="@string/menu_help"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_information" />
        <item
                    android:id="@+id/menu_main_about"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_information"
                    android:title="@string/menuabout_us" />
</menu>
```

I need to space between icon and border in menu to be clear show image please
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRtB5.jpg)

I want show icon in overflow menu of Toolbar like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKUeU.png)

but i face a problem when I click to show options menu in tool bar the icon of item menu overlapping or hidden part from icon in border , I have the following toolbar:

```
     <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutbar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_6sdp">
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: i would recommend never using toolbar, simple remove default tool bar using NoActionBar in theme, and now create your own tool bar in xml and call it where ever you want! in your app theme     <style name="Theme.AppiumApp2" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">

Comment: i used it , the same problem face me in toolbar when call menu between icon and border

Comment: After using custom toll bar there should be no problem! you shoud not use items at all, simple create an xml (tool bar) and design what every you want ,, if you wan hamberger or item list something like that, simply use xml ,, List View is available for this purpose, make it GONE and when You want it visible set this list view Visible,,
if you still did not get it, just edit your question want exactly you want your toolbar look like, i will give details answer with code.

Comment: I want show  icon in overflow menu of Toolbar , I want edit my question to see tool bar xml and also descried what i went by use image , keep on touch...thanks.

Comment: oK, and You should Check ListView, the menu item in toolbar is actually a list view, you can use list view in xml to make overflow menu.

Comment: can you see a new edit and describe me what i want?

Comment: I have added the answer,, the toolbar xml, you can design it like you want,, and than use it where ever you want,,

Comment: Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/teal_200"
android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/real_back"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:text="ABC"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Birthday Card"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    
    
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>  
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/word"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/end"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"/>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add This is the layout where in use it

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/topbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:visibility="gone" 
    android:entries="@array/listarray"/>
```

Create this array in value/string.xml

```
    <string-array name="listarray">
    <item>ABCC</item>
    <item>ABCD</item>
    <item>EFDD</item>

    </string-array>
```

Now what will do in activity is,,,

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.listshow);
    ListView listView= findViewById(R.id.listview);
    textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            
            if(listView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            else {
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
       id) {
            
            if(position ==0 ){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "P1!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if(position ==1){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "p2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Styling toolbar menu item title](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57887764/styling-toolbar-menu-item-title)

Specifically, you can specify a custom layout for menu items using the `actionLayout` parameter as demonstrated:

`android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_layout"`

Comment: I use it (android:actionLayout="@layout/custom_layout") in menu, is it right ?

Comment: i have the following tool bar :

Comment: <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_6sdp">
            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_24sdp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />